# How to specify the buffer mode on the command line?

Tags: buffers, major-mode, command-line-arguments

I want to open a file in `makefile-gmake` mode.  Is there a way to do this from the command line?

I'm looking for something like:

```
$ emacs -m makefile-gmake filename
```

I do not want to change any config files or embed a mode comment in the file itself.  I want a solution that works for any `filename`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `--eval` command line argument:

```
emacs filename --eval "(makefile-gmake-mode)"
```

Comment: Alternatively, I think `-f makefile-gmake-mode` might also work.

Comment: Thanks!  Both `--eval` and `-f` work, as long as they occur *after* `filename`.